# jqgrid php SELECT query problems

Tags: jqgrid

I am attempting to use a variable in my SELECT statement but I'm running into some very strange problems .code below.

**do not work,none data!**

Code:

$fid= $_GET['f'];
    echo $fid;//prints 3
    $SQL = "SELECT threadid, thumb, title, stage, status, startdate ,duedate, forumid FROM thread WHERE forumid = '$fid' ";

**work fine!**

```
**Code:**




   $SQL = "SELECT threadid, thumb, title, stage, status, startdate ,duedate, forumid FROM thread WHERE forumid ='3' ";
```

**thank you!**

**grid.php**

```
    <?php include ("add/add_config.php");?>
<?php include ("php/jqAutocomplete.php");?>
<?php include ("php/jqCalendar.php");?>
<?php include ("php/jqGrid.php");?>
<?php
ini_set("display_errors","1");
$fid= $_GET['f'];

include ("php/jqGridPdo.php");

$conn = new PDO(DB_DSN,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);

$conn->query("SET NAMES utf8");




// Create the jqGrid instance
$grid = new jqGridRender($conn);



echo $fid;

$grid->SelectCommand ="SELECT threadid, thumb, title, stage, status, startdate ,duedate FROM thread WHERE forumid='3'";
//$g="SELECT threadid, thumb, title, stage, status, startdate ,duedate, forumid FROM thread WHERE forumid='$fid'";
//echo $g;
// set the ouput format to json
$grid->dataType = 'json';
$grid->table ="thread";
$grid->setPrimaryKeyId("threadid");


$grid->setUrl('grid.php');
$grid->cacheCount = true;



$grid->addCol(array(
    "name"=>"actions",
    "formatter"=>"actions",
    "editable"=>false,
    "sortable"=>false,
    "resizable"=>false,
    "fixed"=>true,
    "width"=>60,
    "formatoptions"=>array("keys"=>true)
    ), "first");

$grid->setGridOptions(array(
    "caption"=>"cdbdev",
    "rownumbers"=>true, 
     "toppager"=>true, 
    "rowNum"=>10,
    "sortname"=>"threadid",
    "hoverrows"=>true,
    "rowList"=>array(10,20,50),
    "postData"=>array("grid_recs"=>776),    
    "height"=>"auto",
    "width"=>"auto"


    ));


$grid->addCol(array("name"=>"fileToUpload",  "editable"=>true, "edittype"=>"file", "editrules"=>array("edithidden"=>true))); 

$upload = <<<UPLOAD
function(formid) {
//These are needed for fileupload plugin
$(formid).attr("method","POST");
$(formid).attr("action","");
$(formid).attr("enctype","multipart/form-data");

$("<br/><button id='buttonUpload'>Upload</button>").insertAfter("#fileToUpload",formid);
// bind a event
$("#buttonUpload",formid).click(function(){
    $.ajaxFileUpload({
        url:'doajaxfileupload.php',
        secureuri:false,
        fileElementId:'fileToUpload',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data, status) {
            console.log(data);
            if(typeof(data.error) != 'undefined')
            {
                if(data.error != '')
                {
                    alert(data.error);
                }else{
                    $("#fileToUpload").val("");
                    alert(data.msg);
                }
            }
        },
        error: function (data, status, e)
        {
            alert(e);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
}
UPLOAD;

$grid->setJSCode($upload);


$image = <<<CUSTOM
function formatImage(cellValue, options, rowObject) {
    var imageHtml = "<img src='images/" + cellValue + "' originalValue='" + cellValue + "' />";
return imageHtml;
}
function unformatImage(cellValue, options, cellObject) {
    return $(cellObject.html()).attr("originalValue");
}
function formatRating(cellValue, options, rowObject) {
    var color = (parseInt(cellValue) > 0) ? "green" : "red";
    var cellHtml = "<span style='color:" + color + "' originalValue='" +
                   cellValue + "'>" + cellValue + "</span>";
    return cellHtml;
}
function unformatRating(cellValue, options, cellObject) {
    return $(cellObject.html()).attr("originalValue");
}
CUSTOM;
$grid->setJSCode($image);



$grid->setSelect('stage', "SELECT id, name FROM selection where statid=1"); 
$grid->setSelect('status', "SELECT id,name FROM selection where statid=2 ");



$grid->setColProperty("threadid", array( "width"=>80 , "align"=>center));
$grid->setColProperty("stage", array( "width"=>120 , "align"=>center));
$grid->setColProperty("forumid", array( "width"=>0 ,));
$grid->setColProperty("status", array( "width"=>120 , "align"=>center ));


$grid->setColProperty("title", array( "width"=>280, "align"=>center ,"formatter"=>"showlink","formatoptions"=>array("baseLinkUrl"=>"showthread.php", "target"=>"_blank", "idName"=>"t")));

$grid->setColProperty("startdate", array("width"=>130,"align"=>center,
    "formatter"=>"date",
    "formatoptions"=>array("srcformat"=>"Y-m-d H:i:s","newformat"=>"m/d/Y")
    )
);

$grid->setColProperty("duedate", array("width"=>130,"align"=>center,
    "formatter"=>"date",
    "formatoptions"=>array("srcformat"=>"Y-m-d H:i:s","newformat"=>"m/d/Y")
    )
);
$grid->setColProperty("CustomerID", array("editrules"=>array("required"=>true)));
$grid->setAutocomplete("CustomerID",false,"SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName FROM customers WHERE CompanyName LIKE ? ORDER BY CompanyName",null,true,true);

$grid->setUserTime("m/d/Y");
$grid->setUserDate("m/d/Y");
$grid->setDatepicker("startdate",array("buttonOnly"=>false));
$grid->datearray = array('startdate');

$grid->setUserTime("m/d/Y");
$grid->setUserDate("m/d/Y");
$grid->setDatepicker("duedate",array("buttonOnly"=>false));
$grid->datearray = array('duedate');


$grid->navigator = true;


$grid->setNavOptions('navigator', array("cloneToTop"=>true,"excel"=>true,"add"=>false,"edit"=>false,"del"=>false,"view"=>false));

$grid->exportfile = 'Report.xls'; 


$grid->setNavOptions('navigator', array("cloneToTop"=>true,"pdf"=>true,"add"=>false,"edit"=>false,"del"=>false,"view"=>false));


$grid->inlineNav = true;
$grid->setNavEvent('edit', 'onInitializeForm', $upload);



$grid->renderGrid('#grid','#pager',true, null, null, true,true);
$conn = null;


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What SQL engine are you using? If it's MySQL you can use:

```
    echo mysql_error();
```

after running the select to see what error you're having

also try echoing the SELECT statement after generating it to make sure no additional whitespace etc is added to $fid

Comment: I just echo $SQL after that,and it prints " SELECT threadid, thumb, title, stage, status, startdate ,duedate, forumid FROM thread WHERE forumid='3'" ,but no date from mysql

Comment: Well the two SQL commands are identical, so it leads one to think there's some difference elsewhere in the code? Are you using two separate files to do the comparison? If so copy the variable declarations from the file that gets the data from $_GET to the file that is working with the hard coded values, and see if that works?

Comment: thanks a lot!   I am using one file to do the comparison,and debug this on one.

Comment: no! and i do not know what to do ! it just like the problem that in the website http://www.trirand.net/forum/default.aspx?g=posts&t=2847

Comment: It just set session of the variable value ,thus it works fine!